# Why 'this' is not allowed in static methods?

Tags: java, static

I know `this` represents the object invoking the method and `static` methods are not bound to any object but my question is still you can invoke static method on class object .

Why java has made this thing available and not for `this` ?

Comment: Btw. `this` is not the object invoking the method, is the object the method belong to.

Comment: (What would `this` mean in a *static* method? Classes are not "first class objects", discounting exposure via `Class`... I really wish they were, but alas this is Java and not Ruby or Python.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`this` points to the current instance of the class.

Static methods are associated with a class, not an instance, so there's nothing for `this` to point to.

Here's an example:

```
public class Foo {
    private String name; 

    public static void someClassMethod() { System.out.println("associated with a class"); }

    public Foo(String n) { this.name = n; }

    public String getName() { return this.name; }
    public void setName(String n) { this.name = n; }
    public void doAnotherThing() { 
       Foo.someClassMethod();   // This is what is really happening when you call a static method in an non-static method.
    }
}
```

Comment: then why java allows you to invoke static method on class object?

Comment: Why?  Because it's defined for a class object.

Comment: it seems simple answer is Java is defined like this :)

Comment: @amicngh static methods are shared between all the instances of the class, so that why any instance can call a static method. While `this` points to the current instance, and when you are calling `this` from inside a static method, how can Java determines which instance `this` points to? Remember that a static method can be invoked also from an instance of another class.

Comment: @amicngh It is indeed the simple answer, but as you already knew it, why did you ask the question?

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer: `this` is not defined outside of a non-static method.

Calling static methods on an instance is a syntactic shorthand, which I don't agree should exist.

Comment: +1 - I agree.  I like to associate static methods explicitly with their class to make this clear.  No guessing that way.

Answer (score 1):

From every point of view `this` always means **this object**, so giving possibility for meaning *this class* could lead to multiple bugs

Comment: still you can invoke static method on class object/ why?

Comment: @amicngh: because that is how Java is defined.

Comment: Because it's allowed, but as @Amadan said - it should not exists to make things clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The difference here is between a **class** and an **object**. A non-static method is called on an object, while a static method is Called on a class.

You can see a Class as a blueprint, with which Objects are built. 
A class `House` has a static method `hasDoor()` (which will return `true`), while an object of the type `House` can have a method `openDoor()`. You can't open the door of a blueprint.

One can call `House.hasDoor()`, but not `House.openDoor()`. One can call

```
House h = new House();
h.openDoor();
```

While you can call `h.hasDoor()`, this is a bit nasty and should be avoided in most cases